# backBarButtonItem not getting displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I know `viewcontroller's` navigation item's `backBarButtonItem` gets displayed when another view controller is pushed on stack and this is 2nd `viewcontroller` from top.

I have viewcontroller A which have following in `viewDidLoad`

```
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
 [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:[UIBarButtonItem itemWithImageNamed:@"ic_header_slide" selectedImage:nil target:nil action:nil]];
}
```

When I push `viewcontroller B`, this custom back button is not getting displayed, instead I see default back button which iOS creates.

A extends `UITableViewController` and B extends `UIViewController`. I am not setting `leftBarButtonItem`, `leftBarButtonItems`, `rightBarButtonItem`, `rightBarButtonItems` in any of these navigationItem.

EDIT
I have read about setting leftBarButtonItems. setting leftbarbuttonitems on B works. but I think setting backBarButtonItem on A is correct way of doing that. It is also mentioned in documentation but not working in my case. I want to ask whether there is bug in backBarButtonItem or I have some misunderstanding the way it works and I am not doing it correctly.

Comment: you add custom bar button try or not i think its working in your problem.

Comment: I have read about it. setting leftbaritems on B works. but I think setting backBarButtonItem on A is correct way of doing that. It is also mentioned in documentation but not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the default back button of the navigation bar use,

```
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=TRUE;
```

Also use the following method to add the custom BarButtons,

```
- (NSArray*)getLeftNavButtons:(NSString*)image andTarget:(id)target andFrame:(CGRect)frame andSpace:(int)fixedSpace
{
   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   button.frame = frame;
   button.clipsToBounds = YES;
   [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:image] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button addTarget:target action:@selector(leftNavBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:button];

   if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7"))
   {
     UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                       target:nil action:nil];
     negativeSpacer.width = fixedSpace;
     return @[negativeSpacer,barButton];
   }
   else{
     return @[barButton];
   }

   return @[barButton];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override the default

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
back.title = @"Pick Me";
back.image = @"Your image";
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:back];
```

Answer (score 0):

## Set Right Bar Button Item

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];

    UIImage *img1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit"];
    CGRect frameimg1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, img1.size.width, img1.size.height);
    UIButton *signOut=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:frameimg1];
    [signOut setBackgroundImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [signOut addTarget:self action:@selector(btnEditClicked:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//    [signOut setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:signOut];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barButton;
```

## Set Left Bar Button Item

```
  UIImage *img11=[UIImage imageNamed:@"home"];
    CGRect frameimg11 = CGRectMake(0, 0, img11.size.width, img11.size.height);
    UIButton *signOut1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:frameimg11];
    [signOut1 setBackgroundImage:img11 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [signOut1 addTarget:self action:@selector(showLeftMenuPressed:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton1=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:signOut1];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=barButton1;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=ColorNav;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=FALSE;
```

## Set Navigation Title & Color

```
   self.title = titletext;
   [[[self navigationController] navigationBar]setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor}];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! leftBarButtonItem works. I want to ask whether there is bug in backBarButtonItem or I have some misunderstanding the way it works?

Comment: @hridayesh, if you satiesfied then please upvote answer.

Comment: @hridayesh, actually i dont know the perfectr answer but try to set nil, and then again alloc init it. and set again, it should be work.

Comment: Thanks. I want to style navigation bar for certain controllers. should i change styling of global bar on viewwillappear and reset on viewwill disappear? or there is some better way where i define styling in viewcontroller without needing to reset to default?

Comment: I have tried setting nil then alloc init but it didnt work and I continued to see default button